# AD import Error in SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: user-profile-service, active-directory, active-directory-import

Hello I need support to solve the issue below:

I have have setup AD user profile import on SharePoint 2013 and it worked fine for months, but since a few days the synchronization to AD is failing. I got the  errors below:

Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Configure synchronization connections :

***An error occurred while accessing the SQL Server database or the SharePoint Server Search service.***

I got also in windows event viewer -> applications:

***The Execute method of the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ADImport.UserProfileADImportJob task definition
(ID 3da5c9dd-c1be-4d12-9ef9-1686e07780cf) generated an exception. Additional information is available below.
NeedsFullImport***

I already performed an IISRESET with no success.

Answer (score 0):

To help you, can you provide us more information : 
- the account that SharePoint uses to connect to AD, did he have the permission "Replicate Directory Changes permission".
-had u done the Configure profile synchronization [the Configure profile synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx)
-had the user credetentials had been modified in the AD.
-Can u provide us more log.